Can't find step in proof that requires sets to be non-empty (sets, cartesian products, quantifier logic)
This question is about where in a proof I need to assert that a set is non-empty.
The following is Exercise 3.5.6 from Tao's Analysis I 4th ed.

Let $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ be non-empty sets. Show that $A \times B \subseteq C \times D$ if and only if $A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq D$, and that $A \times B = C \times D$ if and only if $A = C$ and $B = D$.
What happens if some or all of the hypotheses that the $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are non-empty are removed?

For now I am only focussing on the first part of the exercise.
Question: Below is my proof. I can't identify which step requires some or all of the sets to be non-empty. This could be because my proof is flawed.

My Proof
To show $A \times B \subseteq C \times D$ if and only if $A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq D$ we need to prove the following two statements:

$A \times B \subseteq C \times D \implies A \subseteq C \land B \subseteq D$
$A \subseteq C \land B \subseteq D \implies A \times B \subseteq C \times D$

~-~
Let's start with the second statement as it easier to prove. The assumption is $A \subseteq C \land B \subseteq D$.
Consider $A \times B$.
$$(x,y) \in A \times B \iff (x,y) \in \{(a,b) : a \in A, b \in B\}$$
By assumption, $a \in A \implies a \in C$, and $b \in B \implies b \in D$. Thus,
$$(x,y) \in A \times B \implies (x,y) \in \{(a,b) : a \in C, b \in D\}$$
That is, $A \times B \subseteq C \times D$.
We have shown $A \subseteq C \land B \subseteq D \implies A \times B \subseteq C \times D$.
~-~
Let's now consider the first statement, which is of the form $P \implies Q$. We can prove this if we can show the logically equivalent contrapositive is true, $\neg Q \implies \neg P$.
Thus we want to show
$$\neg (A \subseteq C \land B \subseteq D) \implies \neg (A \times B \subseteq C \times D)$$
which is equivalent to
$$(A \not \subseteq C) \lor (B \not \subseteq D) \implies  (A \times B) \not \subseteq (C \times D)$$
The LHS tells us that either or both of the following are true:

$\exists x \; [x \in A \land x \notin C]$
$\exists y \; [y \in B \land y \notin D]$

Consider $A \times B$.
$$(x,y) \in A \times B \iff (x,y) \in \{(a,b) : a \in A, b \in B\}$$
So there exists an $(x,y) \in A \times B$ which does not meet the membership criteria of $C \times D$
$$(x',y') \in C \times D \iff (x',y') \in \{(c,d) : c \in C, d \in D\}$$
This is because there exists an $(x,y)$ where either, $x \in A \land x \notin C$, or $y \in B \land y \notin D$, or both.
And so, $(A \times B) \not \subseteq (C \times D)$.
So, by contraposition, we have shown $A \times B \subseteq C \times D \implies A \subseteq C \land B \subseteq D$.
~-~
By showing both statements, we have shown $A \times B \subseteq C \times D \iff A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq D$. $\square$

Discussion
The exercise strongly hints that the proofs require asserting that some or all of the sets are non-empty.
I am struggling with this (self-teaching, beginner).
My best guess is that the existence of an $x$ such that $x \in A \land x \notin C$ requires $A$ to be non-empty. And similarly for the existence of a $y$ such that $y \in B \land y \notin D$ requires $B$ to be non-empty.
A second guess relates to the following statement:
$$(A \not \subseteq C) \lor (B \not \subseteq D) \implies  (A \times B) \not \subseteq (C \times D)$$
Here, an empty $A$ makes $(A \not \subseteq C)$ false because the empty set is a subset of all sets. But if $B£ is non-empty, then the antecedent to the implication can still be true ... so I remain puzzled and uneducated on this matter.

Seems like you're on the right track. Suppose that $A$ is nonempty. What is $A \times \emptyset$?

Hint: Consider what happens if $A=C=\emptyset$.

$A \times \emptyset = \emptyset$. This does not seem to invalidate the original claim that $A \times B \subseteq C \times D \iff A \subseteq C \land B \subseteq D$ as the empty set is a subset of all sets. What am I missing?

If $C$ is empty then $A$ must be empty for the original claim to be valid, because the only subset of an empty set is an empty set. Again, this doesn't seem the path that leads to $A$ or $B$ being non-empty.

You've said that either or both of $$\exists x[x\in A\wedge x\notin C]\tag{$1$}$$ $$\exists y[y\in B\wedge y\notin C].\tag{$2$}$$
Your next line is $$\text{there exists }(x,y)\ldots\tag{$C$}.$$ But if only $(1)$ is true and $(2)$ is not, then where did this $y$ in $(C)$ come from?. If only $(2)$ is true, then you don't have an $x$ to put into $(C)$. Basically, $(1)$ or $(2)$ gives you an $x$ or a $y$, but not necessarily both, but the way you subsequently continued the proof assumes the existence of either an $x$ satisfying $(1)$ and a $y\in B$ (not necessarily satisfying $(2)$), or a $y$ satisfying $(2)$ and an $x\in A$ (not necessarily satisfying $(1)$). Unraveling this will tell you why non-emptiness is necessary.

thanks, this is very helpful in developing my understanding. So for $x$ and $y$ to exist, both $A$ and $B$ must be non-empty. However, an empty $A$ or $B$ doesn't seem to invalidate the original claim $A \times B \subseteq C \times D \iff A \subseteq C \land B \subseteq D$ because $A \times B = \emptyset$ is a subset of any set, including the empty set, and that doesn't contradict the claim. What am I still missing?

One direction of $A\times B\subset C\times D \Leftrightarrow A\subset C\wedge B\subset D$ is still valid. The $\Leftarrow$ is still valid (as you've said).
But since $A\times B=\varnothing$ is a subset of any set, and this occurs if either $A=\varnothing$ or $B=\varnothing$, it causes the condition on the left to occur too frequently, and the $\Rightarrow$ doesn't necessarily hold if $A$ or $B$ is empty.
For example, $A=\varnothing$, $B=\mathbb{R}$, $C=$ anything, and $D=\mathbb{Q}$. Then $\varnothing\times \mathbb{R}=\varnothing\subset C\times D$, but $B\not\subset D$.

More specifically, if $A=\varnothing$, then $A\times B=\varnothing$, so $A\times B$ doesn't tell us anything about $B$. In particular, it cannot tell us anything about the relationship between $B$ and $D$, and we cannot conclude that $B\subset D$. In fact, if $A=\varnothing$, $A\times B\subset C\times D$ for any $B,C,D$.
I like to think of it as multiplying by zero. If $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ and $a=0$, then $ab$ loses all information about $b$. If $A=\varnothing$, then $A\times B=\varnothing$, and we lose all information about $B$.

Thanks  again - this is really helpful intuition "multiply by zero and lose information". My final question then is how to structure an argument in a proof to say this. It has to be more concrete than the "multiply by zero loses information", and I am hoping there is a direct argument which would be more pleasing than a counter-example. I guess what I'm looking for is a similar hint to the one you have in your Answer above.

In this situation, we're faced with the question of "what happens if some or all of the hypotheses that some or all of $A,B,C,D$ are removed?" This is kind of an open-ended question. If we're not asked to prove anything, examples, counterexamples, and informal discussion could be viewed as perfectly sufficient. A statement such as "If $A=\varnothing$, then $A\times B\subset C\times D$ for any sets $B,C,D$, so no relationship need exist between $B$ and $D$ in this case" fully elucidates the case $A=\varnothing$. Not even really anything to prove in that situation.

The "no relationship need exist between $B$ and $D$" is how I would more formally try to relate the "losing information about $B$ intuition.
If you wanted to take it as far as it can go, we know what happens when $A,B,C,D$ are all non-empty, and we know what happens when $A=\varnothing$. By symmetry, we also know what happens when $B=\varnothing$. What if $C=\varnothing$? Which directions of the implication still hold, and if they fail, what, if anything, can we say about which relations imply which others?

thank you - will these comments, I feel the question is answered and have marked it as such. I want to say I appreciate your helpful guidance.

As I was writing this up properly I realised that if both $A$ and $B$ are empty,  then the statement $A \times B \subseteq C \times D \iff A \subseteq C \land B \subseteq D$ is valid. So the statement only fails if $A=\emptyset$ or $B=\emptyset$, but NOT both. Am I deeply mistaken?

You are correct.
