proof of part of Tao Analysis I 3.5.6 too simple? (sets, cartesian products, logic)
I came up with a simpler solution to one part of Tao's Analysis I 4th ed exercise 3.5.6.
Question: Several online solutions, and the one I originally developed (with help), use proof by contraposition, but this one doesn't and is simpler. I suspect there is a flaw - so I'm asking what the error is - that will help me learn.

Exercise 3.5.6
Let $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ be non-empty sets. Show that $A \times B \subseteq C \times D$ if and only if $A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq D$, and that $A \times B = C \times D$ if and only if $A = C$ and $B = D$.
What happens if some or all of the hypotheses that the $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are non-empty are removed?


My Proof
To show $A \times B \subseteq C \times D$ if and only if $A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq D$ we need to prove the following two statements:

$A \times B \subseteq C \times D \implies A \subseteq C \land B \subseteq D$
$A \subseteq C \land B \subseteq D \implies A \times B \subseteq C \times D$

However, this question is only relevant to proving the first statement.
We want to show:
$$A \times B \subseteq C \times D \implies A \subseteq C \land B \subseteq D$$
We assume $A \times B \subseteq C \times D$. This means:
$$ (x,y) \in \{(a,b): a \in A \land b \in B\} \implies (x,y) \in \{(c,d): c \in D \land d \in D\} $$
That is,
$$ (x \in A \implies x \in C ) \land (y \in B \implies y \in D)$$
Which is the equivalent of $A \subseteq C \land B \subseteq D$, what we wanted to show.

My Thoughts
This seems too simple. I am no expert (beginner, self-teaching) and I can only guess that the step from

$ (x,y) \in \{(a,b): a \in A \land b \in B\} \implies (x,y) \in \{(c,d): c \in D \land d \in D\} $

to the following

$ (x \in A \implies x \in C ) \land (y \in B \implies y \in D)$

is where the error lies.
Regarding non-empty sets, the antecedent in $$ (x,y) \in \{(a,b): a \in A \land b \in B\} \implies (x,y) \in \{(c,d): c \in D \land d \in D\} $$ seems to require $A$ and $B$ are non-empty, however the issue of vacuously true implications makes me unsure.

The step you pointed is not an error but needs a proof. I gave you one some days ago https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4889842

You note that if $(x,y) \in A\times B$ then $(x,y)\in C\times D$ and so $x \in C$.  But what if $a \in A$ but $a$ is not the first time of any $(x,y) \in A\times B$?  YOu didn't consider that and that is why it seems too simple.  Now, obviously every $a\in A$ must be a first term of some $(x,y)\in A\times B$, but... you have to show that.

hi @fleablood - thanks for your reply. In my (perhaps flawed) view, every $a \in A$ is a first term in $(x,y) \in A \times B$ because that is the definition of cartesian products. What am I missing?

No, you are correct.  But basically we can say for every $a\in A$ and every $b\in B$ we have $(a,b)\in A\times B\subset C\times D$ so $(a,b) \in C\times D$ so $a \in C$ and $b\in D$ so $A\subset C$ (as the $a$ was arbitrary) and $B\subset D$.  If we start with $(x,y) \in A\times B$, we can't really be claiming we have doing it for an arbitrary $x \in A$.  It's minor and others might say I'm being beyond picky but... you said it was simpler than Tao's? What was Tao's solution?

Thanks, so a simple proof is possible. Tao doesn't provide solutions but several online solutions prove the first statement $P \implies Q$ by proving the contrapositive $\neg Q \implies \neg P$, and I explored this here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4892725/cant-find-step-in-proof-that-requires-sets-to-be-non-empty-sets-cartesian-pro .. @AnneBauval who also provided help also recommended the contrapositive approach, and I wonder why if that's unnecessarily complex.

The step you pointed is not an error but needs a proof. If you really want to convert this (imo simpler) contrapositive proof into a direct one, here it goes:
Assuming $A,B\ne\varnothing$ and $$\forall x\forall y\quad[(x \in A \land y \in B) \implies (x \in C\land y \in D)],$$
let us prove
$$\forall x\forall y\quad[(x\in A \implies x \in C) \land (y \in B \implies y \in D)].$$
By symmetry, it is sufficient to prove
$$\forall x\quad(x\in A \implies x \in C).$$
So, let $a$ be an arbitrary element of $A$. In order to prove that $a\in C$, pick some element $b\in B$ (there exists at least one, by hypothesis). From $a \in A$ and $b\in B$, we derive $a\in C$ and $b\in D$. In particular, $a\in C$, q.e.d.

Thanks @AnneBauval - the two approaches are helpful for my learning.

If $A$ and $B$ are both empty, then the claim $A \times B \subseteq C \times D \implies A \subseteq C \land B \subseteq D$ still seems to hold. Is the non-empty requirement that $A$ exclusive-or $B$ are non-empty?

If only one of them is empty, the claim doesn't hold (as shown at the beginning of my answer some days ago). If both are empty, it does hold but this case is uninteresting.This is why the explicit requirement is that both are non-empty.

Hi @annebauval - if you have the patience, can you explain which step in your answer from a few days ago is the one that makes clear that if both $A$ and $B$ are empty the claim still holds. I'm only asking because my aim is to get better at the logical meaning of the algebra that I sometimes do mechanically without thinking..

It is the only thing I didn't show in my answer from a few days ago, but is is obvious: if $A=B=\varnothing$ then  $A\subset C\land B\subset D$ holds, hence so does $(A\times B\subset C\times D)\implies(A\subset C\land B\subset D).$
